# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc stored into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having troubles pulling a row from sql query and storing it into an array. Here is my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT water, importdate
        FROM customer_table
        WHERE customer_number = '" . $custNum . "';";
        $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
        echo $sql . "<br>";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db_connection,$sql);

        // set array
        $array = array();

        // look through query
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        // add each row returned into an array
        $array[] = $row;
        }
        print_r($array);
```

This is what the output looks like when I print the array,

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [water] => 23 
        [importdate] => 2014-03-29 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [water] => 33 
        [importdate] => 2015-02-22 ) 
    )
```

While it is storing, I am stuck at trying to figure out how to copy each row into the array so it looks like this,

```
Array ( 
    [water] => 23 
    [importdate] => 2014-03-29
) 
Array ( 
    [water] => 33 
    [importdate] => 2015-02-22
)
```

Which is each row stored in $row.

What I am going for is that I need to pull a list of bill amount and dates from the same customer from my database and then display each month by date. Showing the current months bill.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i think the result is what you want? `$array[0] == array('water' => 23, 'importdate' => '2014-03-29')` etc

Comment: It looks like you want multiple arrays then. An array needs a key for every value, and since you're not explicitly defining one, it defaults to 0 and increments from there

Comment: I'm convinced you already have the result you want. later on you can loop over it like this: `foreach($array as $row) { print_r($row); }` and you have exactly what you started with, each row by itself

Answer (score 1):

Who is containing the objects when you say?

```
Array ( 
    [water] => 23 
    [importdate] => 2014-03-29
)
 Array ( 
    [water] => 33 
    [importdate] => 2015-02-22
)
```

Nothing.. You need to have an array containing this arrays, or you need to have multiple arrays indexed somewhere, what is basically an array with arrays. So nothing wrong with that format..

Why you need this format specifically? It doesn't make sense..

Comment: I dont technically need this format. I am just trying to do a sql call to get all the customers current and past billing months. I am using mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) to pull each row of data and I want each row of data stored in an assoc array so I can pass it to another page for display. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @LeSlasha your current output is already the best format you can have to pass through.. When you have multiple objects of same type (bills) and you want to index it, you will need an array.. Try to better explain what you want to make on display, because your DB reading is just fine..

Answer (score -1):

I ended up changing the way I stored the data. I pulled the row apart and put them into two different arrays and stored them in the session. Below is the code.

```
            // set array
            $costArray = array();
            $dateArray = array();
            $i = 0;

            // look through query
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

              // add each row returned into an array
              $array[] = $row;

              //print_r($row);

              list($id,$two) = each($row);
              $costArray[$i] = $two;

              //echo "Total bill" . $two;

              list($id,$two) = each($row);
              $dateArray[$i] = $two;

              $i++;

            }
            $_SESSION['cost'] = $costArray;
            $_SESSION['date'] = $dateArray;
```

They are both the same length so I ended up pulling the arrays out of the session, storing them into a variable and displaying them like this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($costArray); ++$i) {
echo $dateArray[$i]. " $" . $costArray[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

Thanks for all your help, it made me realize how hard I was making it.